# Как создать торрент файл?

Tags: python, torrent

Я пытаюсь создать торрент файл, используя [torf](https://github.com/rndusr/torf).

Для тестов я использую один пк и просто обычный текстовый файл с надписью `hello word`. После выполнения кода из примера:

```
from torf import Torrent

t = Torrent(path='test.txt',
            trackers=['https://tracker1.example.org:1234/announce',
                      'https://tracker2.example.org:5678/announce'],
            comment='This is a comment')
t.private = True
t.generate()
t.write('my.torrent')
```

я запускаю новый файл `my.torrent` в программе `µTorrent`.

После идет `finding to peers`, но дальше `Connecting to peers` дело не идет...
Я знаю что для работы нужен торрент трекер, но где мне его найти?
При попытке найти его в интернете мне просто дается сайт с кучей торрент файлов, как ThePirateBay или Rutor.org...

Кто нибудь может протестировать у себя и сказать, что я делаю не так?

**Update**

В `uTorrent` я нашел два трекера

udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce
udp://tracker.opentrackr.org:1337/announce

В качестве теста я попробовал создать торрент через `uTorrent`
Файл назвал `test.torrent`
И в окне началась раздача `Seeding`
После я удалил его из очереди на раздачу
и запустил `test.torrent` снова
Результат был такойже как и с `my.torrent`
Вместо того что бы раздавать он пытается скачать его
Как мне начать раздавать файл? или это делается автоматически после создания террент файла?

Comment: предлагаю начать с выяснения что такое торрент трекер

Comment: Совершенно верно. Для работынужен торрент трекер, который раздаст другим пользователям торрент файл. Причем, чтобы раздача началась - Вам нужно после публикации файла скачать его, и запустить торрент - клиент: тогда то и начнётся раздача.

Comment: @S.H. @Эникейщик Я это прекрасно понимаю. Но как мне их искать? Повторюсь **При попытке найти его в интернете мне просто дается сайт с кучей торрент файлов.** Как и где мне искать ссылки для переменной `trackers` хотябы для тестов.

Comment: Я уже пытался ввести `trackers=['http://1337.abcvg.info:80/announce','http://87.110.238.140:6969/announce']` но скачивания не происходит.

Comment: Вам попадаются торрент - трекеры с кучей торрент файлов. Вы - теоретически - можете добавить к этой куче файлов свой. Но у трекеров есть правила, по которым Ваш тестовый файл, скорее всего, опубликовать не удастся. Выход - поставить свой торрент -  трекер. Гуглить по docker torrent server.

Comment: @S.H. А можно ли как нибудь без создания собственного трекера? 
Так как это лишняя нагрузка на сервер. А я хочу максимально облегчить сайт.
Я хочу знать хотя бы этот код может работать или нет. 
Под сайтом с кучей торрентов я подразумевал просто сайт как [ThePirateBay](https://thepiratebay10.org/) или [Rutor.org](http://new-rutor.org/)
Где есть есть куча торрентов для скачивания а как загрузить нигде инструкции нет. Я вопрос обновил

Comment: > а как загрузить нигде инструкции нет - обычно такие сайты используют при помощи торрент - клиентов. piratebay - просто поисковик по другим торрент - трекерам, поэтому у них такая лаконичная первая страница. У рутрекера инструкция по загрузке и использованию трекера - есть на первой странице.

Comment: @S.H. Я на странице rutor.org ничего не нашел только вкладку **Залить** Которая недоступна. Я обновил вопрос.

Comment: "**сайт с кучей торрент файлов**" и есть **торрент трекер**!

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, у Вас возникает проблема из за того, что нет общей картины того, как работает bittorrent протокол и сеть торрентов вообще.

Поэтому я расскажу несколько вещей на примере, а Вы можете задать вопросы в комментариях.

Предположим, я хочу раздать файл с фильмом. Я создаю торрент (это одна из функций моего торрент - клиента) и публикую СТРАНИЦУ, посвященную этому фильму, на торрент - трекере.

Зачем я это делаю? Потому что другие пользователи ищут файлы по содержанию - названиям, ключевым словам и так далее.

При публикации страницы я отдал торрент - трекеру файл *.torrent

Пускай пользователь1 обратил внимание на этот фильм и захотел его себе скачать. Он забирате с трекера файл *.torrent. Этот то же файл, котрый я туда положил? Не совсем. К файлу подмешан так называемый passkey -эта штука, которая позволяет трекеру отличить одного пользователя от другого. Уникальный идентификатор пользователя трекера. Он нужен, чтобы считать на трекере статистику пользователей - кто сколько скачал и раздал.

Когда пользователь1 поставил фильм "на закачку", его торрент-клиент делает запрос к трекеру ("анонс") и говорит "скажи, у кого есть этот фильм?". Так как сейчас единственный обладатель фильма - я, то трекер сообщает пользователю1 мой внешний IP и порт. Беэ этой информации - клиент пользователя1 не знал бы, куда надо подключаться.

Вот с этого момента я начинаю отдавать фильм пользователю1, небольшими кусочками, номер котрых выбиарется случайно.

Пускай в середине этого процесса еще кто то хочет скачать этот же фильм. Ему торрент - трекер даст адреса и порты уже двух клиентов, и им обоим можно будет посылать запросы на закачку кусочков фильма.

Что здесь важно? что трекер служит точкой обмена информацией между теми, у кого есть файл, и теми, кто хочет его себе скачать. Эта информация - не сам файл, а его уникальный иддентификатор и адреса и порты участников обмена. Таким образом, без торрент - трекера процесс обмена файлами не начнётся.

Окончательный ли это приговор? Не совсем. Дело в том, что есть еще механизм DHT, очень красивая штука, работающая по принципу "делай добро и бросай его в воду". DHT позволяет находить файлы по уникальному хешу. Таблица "хешей всех файлов на свете" виртуально существует, будучи "размазанной" по множеству клиентов, занимающихся раздачей файлов.

Поэтому при помощи DHT действительно можно обменяться файлами, не используя трекер. Его можно даже вообще не указывать. Но при этом сам torrent - файл или магнет - ссылку нужно передать от того, кто раздаёт файл тому, кто его хочет скачать каким то способом - послать по электронной почте, например.

Еще можно почитать здесь же, на СО вопрос про "ядро трекера". Еще - Вы можете конкретизировать свой вопрос, и можете поставить эксперимент с участием двух компьютеров - возможно, тогда Вам всё станет понятно.

Небольшое дополнение. "Вместо того что бы раздавать он пытается скачать его" -да, это так. Это одна из самых неочевидных и выносящих мозг особенностей терекера. Когад вы опубликовали файл, вы должны первым делом скачать именно этот торрент, но уже с трекера. Дело в том, что для трекера все клиенты - и тот, кто публикует, и тот, кто качает - равны между собой. Нет "автора" и "не автора", есть просто равноправные участники обмена, у каждого из которых есть части файла. А у вас с самого начала есть 100% частей файла. Поэтому одна из частей инструкции по публикации файлов - "После отправки фала на торрент трекер вам нужно его скачать, и поставить на закачку у самого себя в ту же директорию, где лежат оригинальные файлы. ... Обратите свое внимание, что этот торрент отличается от того, который был залит на трекер. К нему добавился пасскей, по которому Вас будет узнавать трекер."

Кстати, сами по себе FAQ даже не заблокированы, по моему: [терминология](http://rutracker.wiki/Bittorrent/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B)

Еще одно дополнение. Случайо наткнулся на ссылку именно о том, как передать самому себе на другой компьютер файл через торрент - протокол (по моему, задача, похожая на ту, о которой Вы спрашивали): [инструкция по передаче файлов](https://wd-x.ru/peredaem-fajly-s-kompyutera-na-kompyuter-s-pomoshhyu-torrent-razdachi/)

Успехов!

Comment: Это правда что я много чего не понимаю про терренты так как впервые имею с ними дело. Спасибо что пытаетесь все мне объяснить. Но проблема в том что в своей программе использую `torf` а не `uTorrent`. Хоть у меня есть обе программы. Но первоначальная задача раздать торрент файл на python Вы сказали **Когад вы опубликовали файл, вы должны первым делом скачать именно этот торрент** Но как мне это сделать с помощью `torf`? При создания торрента в `uTorrent` он делает это автоматически. Но что делает `torf` я не знаю. Такое ощущение что он просто создает ссылку на файл которы никто не раздает.

Comment: Совершенно верно. Это два разных процесса: создание торрент - файла и раздача файла. В раздаче файла участвует торрент - трекер (на этапе обмена информацией о том, у кого этот файл есть). Для содания торрент - файла он совершенно не нужен. Соответственно, если Вы хотите решить задачу "раздать файл при помощи программы на python" - Вам надо кроме создания торрент - файла запрограммировать еще и взаимодействие с трекером. Вообще то, это тоже не рокет-сайенс, потому что есть такая прекрасная штука как libtorrent - но, согласитесь, это уже более сложная задача?

Comment: > Вместо того что бы раздавать он пытается скачать его - там в инструкции написано "После отправки фала на торрент трекер вам нужно его скачать, и поставить на закачку у самого себя в ту же директорию, где лежат оригинальные файлы". При этом торрент - клиент видит, что файл уже есть, и просто проверит его хеш.

Comment: О какой инструкций вы говорите? Я не нашел ничего подобного на `torf`. Я бы хотел что бы это было автоматически а не в ручную. Поэтому и использую вместо `uTorrent` `torf`

Comment: Думаю, сейчас я рассказал Вам все, что мог, о торрент-обмене. Не смогу ничего больше посоветовать :-( инструкция-из того факу, ссылка на которы («терминология») есть в моем ответе

Comment: значит вы не знаете как автоматически раздовать в `torf` но все равно спасибо за разяснения.